# Cisco AnyConnect not Working

Tags: windows-7, networking, 64-bit, vpn, cisco-vpn-client

I'm trying to VPN into work with a new computer.  I get one of two error messages: "Unable to complete connection: Cisco Secure Desktop not installed on the client" or "AnyConnect is not enabled on the VPN server".

Anybody have any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure the svc is enabled. The following document describes how to setups anyconnect on an ASA.

[ASA with Anyconnect](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6120/products_configuration_example09186a00808efbd2.shtml)

The basic commands are:

webvpn

enable outside

svc enable

The document explains it all in detail.

Comment: The link 404s now. Too bad.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, it's because your need to have an AV client installed with the latest virus definitions and/or your Windows personal firewall on.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error, and what fixed it for me was restarting by using `shutdown -r -t 00` as administrator (this ensures it's a real restart).